# Schema.org: one event, multiple locations

Tags: seo, schema.org

I was wondering how to correctly markup a music event that happens in multiple locations with schema.org?

The event is going on in one locations from 21:00 - 01:00 and in the other from 23:00 - 03:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema.org defines that an [event](http://schema.org/Event) is

> […] happening at a certain time and location

So you should specify two [`MusicEvent`](http://schema.org/MusicEvent) items.

Depending on the kind of events, you might have a super event (like a festival) which you could specify with the [`superEvent`](http://schema.org/superEvent) property.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked fine, just wasn't sure of the correct way of doing it before.